# Was bedeutet 'Giftgeber' auf Deutsch, falls überhaupt?

Tags: compound, archaism

Ich dachte, dass "Giftgeber" im Englischen `Poison-giver` bedeuten soll. Aber [hier](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~cd2/drw/e/gi/ftge/giftgeber.htm) sagt eine Seite dass es wirklich `gift-giver` (*Geschenkausteiler*) bedeutet. Wie ist das möglich, wenn jeder Eintrag unter ['das Gift'](http://de-en.dict.cc/?s=gift) Poison bedeutet?

Sie merken sicher, dass das Wort "Giftgeber" selten im ganzen Internet gefunden werden kann.

Was passiert hier?

Comment: Interessant, also haben die Deutschen vor Jahrhunderten "Gift" gesagt und "Geschenk" gemeint. Das wusste ich nicht. Egal, heute denkt kein Deutscher mehr an "Geschenk", wenn er "Gift" sagt. Am besten vergisst Du das ganz schnell wieder :)

Comment: Ob Gift negativ ist oder positiv hängt vom Kontext und der Einstellung des Sprechers ab - Rauschgift und Gegengift seien hier exemplarisch genannt, aber auch für den Kammerjäger oder Mörder ist die Waffe sicher nicht negativ. Davon ab ist das keine Nebenbedeutung, sondern die Bedeutung selbst, um die es sich handelt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed both the English *"to give"*, and *"gift"* share a common etymology with the German *"das Gift"* und *"geben"*:

> *ahd.* (9. Jh.), *mhd. mnd.* **gift** f. *das Geben, Gabe, Geschenk, Gift*, *mnl.* ghifte, ghichte, nl. **gift** f. *Gabe, Gift*, *aengl*. gift, gyft f. n. *Gabe, Belohnung, Brautpreis* <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=gift&view=1)</sup>

It was also used for substances **given** to people for medical reasons, hence propably the shift in meaning.

Today the original meaning still can be found in [*"die Mitgift"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mitgift), whereas *"das Gift"* exclusively is used in the meaning of *poison*.

Note that there also is a shift in gender, where *"die Gift"* (engl. *gift*) was female, whereas *"das Gift"* (engl. *poison*) is neuter.

From the original meaning of someting which was given, the compound noun [*"Giftgeber"*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GG16484) would be from two words with the same meaning. This makes me believe that it may have been used only rarely. It is not used in contemporary German.

Answer (score 6):

Früher war Gift ebenfalls als *Geschenk* bekannt:

[image]

<sup>[Diefenbach, L.; Wülcker, E.: Hoch- und nieder-deutsches Wörterbuch der mittleren und neueren Zeit](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~cd2/drw/F10/diefenwue/s625-626.htm)</sup>

Diese Verwendung ist allerdings veraltet und sollte nicht mehr angewandt werden. Das kommt übrigens aus dem Germanischen und wurde daraus ins Englische weitergezogen.

Answer (score 3):

The first reference links to an entry about the book "Hoch- und nieder-deutsches Wörterbuch der mittleren und neueren Zeit", i.e. Giftgeber was probably used in the positive sense before the meaning of "Gift" shifted. You should not use this in a modern text. However it may not sound like "poison-giver" but like a surname of a potentially famous person used as a comparison.